# How to make binary to hex converter using for loop - Python

Tags: python

Yes, this is homework. 
I have the basic idea. I know that basically I need to introduce a for loop and set if's saying if the value is above 9 then it's a, b, c, and so forth. But what I need is to get the for loop to grab the integer and its index number to calculate and go back and forth and then print out the hex. by the way its an 8 bit binary number and has to come out in two digit hex form.

thanks a lot!!

Comment: How about you write some code, and if it doesn't work, ask us to help fix it.

Comment: I upvoted you just for being really straightforward about the fact that it's homework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a string containing the binary data.

In Python, you can iterate over all sorts of things, strings included. It becomes as simple as this:

```
for char in mystring:
    pass
```

And replace `pass` with your suite (a term meaning a "block" of code). At this point, `char` will be a single-character string. Nice an straight forward.

For getting the character ordinal, investigate `ord` (find help for it yourself, it's not hard and it's good practice).

For converting the number to hex, you could use `%` string formatting with `'%x'`, which will produce a value like '9f', or you could use the `hex` function, which will produce a value like '0x9f'; there are other ways, too.

If you can't figure any thing out, ask; but try to work it out first. It's your homework. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that you've got the binary number in a string, you will want to have an index variable that gets incremented with each iteration of the for loop.  I'm not going to give you the exact code, but consider this:

- [Python's for loop](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) is designed to set the index variable (`for` index `in` list) to each value of a list of values.
- You can use the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function to generate a list of numbers (say, from 0 to 7).
- You can get the character at a given index in a string by using e.g. `binary[index]`.